# passing ImmutableSet in place of Set?

Tags: collections, guava

I have a method that expects a Set parameter.  I want to pass in an empty set, and I don't want any side effects on the Set.

I can do this with collections by passing in:

```
 Collections.unmodifiableSet(Sets.newHashSet())
```

But I want to pass in:

```
 ImmutableSet.of()
```

If I do the former a `Set<Object>` is created and I get "method not applicable for args Set' error.  If I do the latter I get `ImmutableSet<Object>` is created and I get similar error.

This works:

```
 Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<String>())
```

... but seems ugly, and I want to find a Google Collections way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
ImmutableSet.<String>of()
```

This will work too:

```
Collections.<String>emptySet()
```

This syntax is useful for manually specifying type arguments any time the type inference fails. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> emptySet = ImmutableSet.of();
    doStuffWith(emptySet);
}

static void doStuffWith(Set<String> strings) {
    // ...
}
```

because the type inference notices that you are assigning to a `Set<String>` variable and knows that the type parameter must be `String`.